# Trying to add 1 to the end of a quote so it changes the link when I loop it

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is what ive got so far (besides the rest of the code). but when i loop the code, it just pulls the same data 10 times.

```
    for page in range (10):

        my_url = 'https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=switch&_sacat=0&_pgn=' + str(1)


        #Open Collection
        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close

        #html parser
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    
        #html parser
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

There's more code, but this is where i believe the problem is.

Comment: you did not use page variable in loop,so you always fetch the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just changing the page number you can just make a small change to your current `for` loop:

```
 for page_number in range(1, 11):
        my_url = f'https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=switch&_sacat=0&_pgn={page_number}'
```

So, I changed the `range` to go from 1-10, and used an `f-string` to insert the page number value into the `my_url` value.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If it solves your problem could you accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `str(1)` for 10 times in your code - *This will get the data from the same page 10 times*.

You are not using the `page` variable in your URL.

```
for page in range (1,11):

        my_url = 'https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=switch&_sacat=0&_pgn=' + str(page)
```

Comment: This would give 0 for the first page and 9 for the last page because of how range works